# Problem to import data from SQL-DataBase to DataTable

Tags: vb.net

I trying to get data from SQL DataBase into a `DataTable` but I am stuck.
In Excel it works but in VB.net I get an error in near '*' in the folowing code:

```
Dim Strng As String = "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF Select Case * From OPENQUERY(INSQL," _
        & "'SELECT DateTime = convert(nvarchar, DateTime, 21), [Flow.Value], [Temp.Value], [Phase.PhaseNr]" _
        & "FROM WideHistory WHERE wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'" _
        & "And wwQualityRule = 'Extended' And wwVersion = 'Latest' And DateTime = GetDate()')"
    Dim conn As String = "Data Source=" & "**.**.**.**" & ";" _
            & "Initial Catalog=" & "Somedatabase" & ";" _
            & "User Id=" & "someone" & ";" _
            & "Password=" & "someone" & ";" _
            & "Connect Timeout=60;" _
            & "Network Library=dbmssocn;"
    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(conn)
        cnn.Open()
        Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(Strng, cnn)
            dad.Fill(dtb)
        End Using
        cnn.Close()
    End Using
    Dim strDetail
    For Each row As DataRow In dtb.Rows
        strDetail = row.Item("Temp.Value")
    Next row
```

How can I solve this problem?
Sorry to mention is that the error appears at this line of code.

```
dad.Fills(dtb)
```

And  The message I get is:

> An unhandled exception of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

**Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '*'.**

The IP-adress is not the problem. I have removed that for privacy.

Comment: Hi Peter, could you edit your question to include the exception type and message that you're seeing

Comment: " Select Case * " is not correct. For what purpose do you use that "case"? Use just " SELECT * FROM... "

Comment: I use 'Case' because i want to get more then 1 values from different items So as you can see [Flow.value],[Temp.value] and [Phase.Phasenr] those are in different items. but same rows.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, i solved the problem by removing ** 'Case'** and the following **WideHistory WHERE wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic' And wwQualityRule = 'Extended' And wwVersion = 'Latest' And** from the query now the datatable is filled with the data that i also get in Excel.

Comment: When you solve a problem, post an answer and accept it. Don't put the word "solved" in the title. The system keeps track of which questions have been answered, and it doesn't look for the word "solved" in the title.

Comment: Oke Raymond i will keep that in mind for the next time thanks for editing the Title